# Sideload iOS apps on M1 mac if they are not in the App Store

Tags: ios, applications, monterey, apple-silicon

My ISP, China Telecom, has a router/modem that does not have a web interface. They only provide functions like port forwarding in their app, available for iOS.

I have run iOS apps on Mac before, but this app is not listed in the Mac App Store.

How can I sideload this iOS app onto my m1 MacBook?

Edit: I tried PlayCover, but it does not work with SIP enabled, which I don't feel comfortable disabling just for this. Here are the log messages:

```
默认  11:49:26.176114+0800    tccd    AUTHREQ_ATTRIBUTION: msgID=178.39587, attribution={responsible={<TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.Terminal, pid=958, auid=501, euid=501, responsible_path=/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal, binary_path=/System/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal>}, accessing={<TCCDProcess: identifier=me.playcover.PlayCover, pid=31993, auid=501, euid=501, binary_path=/Applications/PlayCover.app/Contents/MacOS/PlayCover>}, requesting={<TCCDProcess: identifier=com.apple.sandboxd, pid=178, auid=0, euid=0, binary_path=/usr/libexec/sandboxd>}, },
默认  11:49:26.337759+0800    PlayCover   Found application <private> to open application <private>
默认  11:49:26.346131+0800    runningboardd   Acquiring assertion targeting app<application.com.sjustfly.SmartTelecom.42066942.42068138(501)> from originator [anon<PlayCover>(501):31993] with description <RBSAssertionDescriptor| "LS launch com.sjustfly.SmartTelecom" ID:214-31993-460124 target:app<application.com.sjustfly.SmartTelecom.42066942.42068138(501)> attributes:[
    <RBSDomainAttribute| domain:"com.apple.launchservicesd" name:"LaunchRoleUserInteractive" sourceEnvironment:"(null)">
    ]>
错误  11:49:26.385066+0800    PlayCover   LAUNCH: RBSLaunchRequest FAILURE <private> com.sjustfly.SmartTelecom <private> 0x0-0x4e94e9 failed with error Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000035c51a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}
错误  11:49:26.385086+0800    PlayCover   LAUNCH: Runningboard launch of com.sjustfly.SmartTelecom <private> returned RBSRequestErrorFailed, error Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000035c51a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}, so returning -10810
错误  11:49:26.385128+0800    PlayCover   LAUNCH: request execute thru runningboard of 0x0-0x4e94e9 com.sjustfly.SmartTelecom/<private> failed with error=Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000035c51a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=153 "Unknown error: 153" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}
默认  11:49:26.392786+0800    PlayCover   -[SFLGenericList _insertItem:atIndex:error:]_block_invoke item: DEC19A61-4C4C-4DC1-8DCF-530421A8AB35 at index: 0 list: com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentApplications
默认  11:49:26.393408+0800    PlayCover   received: com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentApplications
默认  11:49:26.384838+0800    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 214-31993-460124 (target:app<application.com.sjustfly.SmartTelecom.42066942.42068138(501)>) from originator [anon<PlayCover>(501):31993]
错误  11:49:26.393623+0800    PlayCover   LAUNCH: Launch failure with -10810/kLSUnknownErr <private>
```

Manually executing the app in Terminal results in SIGKILL and this error message in Console:

```
Default 11:46:08.647000+0800 kernel proc 32209: set_code_unprotect() error 7 for file "TelecomSteward"
```

Comment: Is "this iOS app" available in the App Store on your Mac?

Comment: @nohillside It's not. That's the reason I'm asking.

Comment: Do you happen to know if this [developer chose catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/mac-catalyst/) or its a pure iOS / iPadOS app?  Still looking for the most general advice - surprisingly hard on Apple Developer as I haven’t figured the right search terms…

Comment: @bmike I looked at the compatibility section and it seems like it only works on iPhone. So not even iPadOS. I guess that means catalyst is off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The developer has choosen not to make the app available for macOS. Therefore the standard Apple setup will not let you run it.

You need to disable SIP and then use a tool, such as for example PlayCover, in order to override that protection and let the app run on your Mac.

Comment: Why do I need to disable SIP? I though AMFI prevents me from running whatever code I want to...

Comment: You need to disable SIP in order to disable AMFI. You specifically mentioned not wanting to disable SIP at all - and that's why I specifically mentioned that this is a requirement. Ofcourse you need to follow the full guide on installing PlayCover.